# Capture DEBUG, INFO log level messages in Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, logging

I would like to see INFO and DEBUG level logs in Heroku but I'm no sure how. Papertrail, for example, only shows WARNING level logs and above and I don't see any option to change that. I'm using python-django, but I don't think that matters. Is there any option to capture all logs in Heroku?

**EDIT**

The terminal logs all the levels correctly in the local env. However, `heroku logs --tail` doesn't. I dont understand why.

Comment: That's not up to the platform - Heroku will show anything that ends up on stdout or stderr (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log).

Comment: @jonrsharpe then, I don't understand why are the logs (INFO, DEBUG) not being displayed in Heroku while they work correctly in the local env.